# MongoDB split array to N-elements array by even element

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Hi i have a question according to MongoDB aggregations.

I want to divide my list of dates

```
"checked" : [
    ISODate("2018-11-01T07:00:00.000+0000"), 
    ISODate("2018-11-01T15:00:00.000+0000"), 
    ISODate("2018-11-02T07:00:00.000+0000"), 
    ISODate("2018-11-02T15:00:00.000+0000"), 
    ISODate("2018-11-03T07:00:00.000+0000"), 
    ISODate("2018-11-03T15:00:00.000+0000"), 
    ISODate("2018-11-04T07:00:00.000+0000"), 
    ISODate("2018-11-04T15:00:00.000+0000"), 
    ISODate("2018-12-01T07:00:00.000+0000"), 
    ISODate("2018-12-01T15:00:00.000+0000"), 
    ISODate("2018-12-02T07:00:00.000+0000"), 
    ISODate("2018-12-02T15:00:00.000+0000"), 
    ISODate("2018-12-03T07:00:00.000+0000"), 
    ISODate("2018-12-03T15:00:00.000+0000"), 
    ISODate("2018-12-04T07:00:00.000+0000"), 
    ISODate("2018-12-04T15:00:00.000+0000")
]
```

Into 2-elements little arrays like this:

```
"checked" : [
    [
        ISODate("2018-11-01T07:00:00.000+0000"), 
        ISODate("2018-11-01T15:00:00.000+0000")
    ],
    [
        ISODate("2018-11-02T07:00:00.000+0000"), 
        ISODate("2018-11-02T15:00:00.000+0000") 
    ],
    [
        ISODate("2018-11-03T07:00:00.000+0000"), 
        ISODate("2018-11-03T15:00:00.000+0000") 
    ],
    ...
]
```

It is possible in aggregation to achieve that?

I saw that there is a $split but works on strings. There is also $reduce, but it's reducing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [$range](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/range/index.html) to generate an array of indexes with `step` parameter set to `2`. Then you just need [$slice](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/) to get an array of 2-element arrays, try:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            checked: {
                $map: {
                    input: { $range: [ 0, { $size: "$checked" }, 2 ] },
                    as: "index",
                    in: { $slice: [ "$checked", "$$index", 2 ] }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Wow i just tried that -it works like a charm. thanks!