# Merge collections up to a fixed size using MongoDB Aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate-functions

I have a collection that looks something like this:

```
{
    "_id" : id1,
    "field1" : 11,
    "field2": 101,
    "localityID" : 27
}
{
    "_id" : id2,
    "field1" : 22,
    "field2": 202,
    "localityID" : 27
}
{
    "_id" : id3,
    "field1" : 33,
    "field2": 303,
    "localityID" : 27
}
{
    "_id" : id4,
    "field1" : 44,
    "field2": 404,
    "localityID" : 27
}
{
    "_id" : id5,
    "field1" : 55,
    "field2": 505,
    "localityID" : 27
}
{
    "_id" : id6,
    "field1" : 66,
    "field2": 606,
    "localityID" : 61
}
{
    "_id" : id4,
    "field1" : 77,
    "field2": 707,
    "localityID" : 61
}
```

Use Case - I want to retrieve and process records having the same `localityID` in batches of size 3.
For tracking purposes, I also want to keep a track of records that were processed in a specific batch

For the same, I want to use MongoDB's aggregation framework in order to combine collections having the same `localityID` but only up to a fixed size (3 as mentioned above).

I want to update the above collection to something like:

```
{
  "_id" : "id111",
  "batchId" : "batch1",
  "localityID": 27,
  "batches": [
     {
         "field1" : 11,
         "field2": 101
     },
     {
         "field1" : 22,
         "field2": 202
     },
     {
         "field1" : 33,
         "field2": 303
     }
  ]
}
{
  "_id" : "id222",
  "batchId" : "batch2",
  "localityID": 27,
  "batches": [
     {
         "field1" : 44,
         "field2": 404
     },
     {
         "field1" : 55,
         "field2": 505
     }
  ]
}
{
  "_id" : "id333",
  "batchId" : "batch1",
  "localityID": 61,
  "batches": [
     {
         "field1" : 66,
         "field2": 606
     },
     {
         "field1" : 77,
         "field2": 707
     }
  ]
}
```

I tried a few combinations of aggregate functions like the one below but was not able to get the desired outcome.

(this was able to combine all the records with the same `localityID` **but in one document only and not in batches**)

```
db.old_collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": { "_id": "$localityID" } },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "old_collection",
    "let": { "lid": "$_id" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$localityID", "$$lid" ] } }},
      { "$project": { "_id": 0, "field1": 1, "field2": 1 } }
    ],
    "as": "batches"
  }},
  {"$out": "new_collection" }
])
```

the above aggregation function produce the following outcome -

```
{
  "_id" : "id111",
  "batchId" : "batch1",
  "localityID": 27,
  "batches": [
     {
         "field1" : 11,
         "field2": 101
     },
     {
         "field1" : 22,
         "field2": 202
     },
     {
         "field1" : 33,
         "field2": 303
     },
     {
         "field1" : 44,
         "field2": 404
     },
     {
         "field1" : 55,
         "field2": 505
     }
  ]
}
{
  "_id" : "id333",
  "batchId" : "batch1",
  "localityID": 61,
  "batches": [
     {
         "field1" : 66,
         "field2": 606
     },
     {
         "field1" : 77,
         "field2": 707
     }
  ]
}
```

Is this possible with Mongo's aggregate framework or would I be better off with something else?

Comment: Your aggregation pipeline does not have any `batchId` field, so your provided outcome is certainly not from this aggregation pipeline. I don't get the logic for `batchId` field.

Comment: Yes @WernfriedDomscheit , `batchId` field is not present in the input. . Value of `batchId` for each `localityID` can be a simple serial number starting from 0 up to the total number of documents created for that `localityID`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53903002/mongodb-split-array-to-n-elements-array-by-even-element).
You can use [$range](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/range/index.html) to generate an array of indexes with step parameter set to some `bucketSize`. Then you just need [$slice](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/) to get an array of size `bucketSize`, try this:

```js
let bucketSize = 3;

db.old_collection.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$localityID",
            id: { $first: "$_id" },
            localityID: { $first: "$localityID" },
            batches: {
                $push: {
                    field1: "$field1",
                    field2: "$field2"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            localityID: "$localityID",
            batches: {
                $map: {
                    input: { $range: [0, { $size: "$batches" }, bucketSize] },
                    as: "index",
                    in: { $slice: ["$batches", "$$index", bucketSize] }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: {
            path: "$batches",
            includeArrayIndex: "batchId"
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            batchId: {
                $concat: [
                    "batch",
                    { $toString: { $add: ["$batchId", 1] } }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    // $sort is optional. You can remove it if not required.
    {
        $sort: {
            localityID: 1,
            batchId: 1
        }
    }
    { $out: "new_collection" }
]);
```

Output

```js
[
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("..."),
        "localityID": 27,
        "batches": [
            {
                "field1": 11,
                "field2": 101
            },
            {
                "field1": 22,
                "field2": 202
            },
            {
                "field1": 33,
                "field2": 303
            }
        ],
        "batchId": "batch1"
    },
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("..."),
        "localityID": 27,
        "batches": [
            {
                "field1": 44,
                "field2": 404
            },
            {
                "field1": 55,
                "field2": 505
            }
        ],
        "batchId": "batch2"
    },
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("..."),
        "localityID": 61,
        "batches": [
            {
                "field1": 66,
                "field2": 606
            },
            {
                "field1": 77,
                "field2": 707
            }
        ],
        "batchId": "batch1"
    }
]
```

Comment: When implementing the above solution for large collections (more than 60 million records), I am getting the following error `$push used too much memory and cannot spill to disk.`. Is there any way we can modify the above solution in order to solve this error. I tried enabling `allowDiskUse` but it did not solve the issue.

Comment: Complete Error Message

`The full response is {"operationTime": {"$timestamp": {"t": 1617712444, "i": 1}}, "ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "$push used too much memory and cannot spill to disk. Memory limit: 104857600 bytes", "code": 146, "codeName": "ExceededMemoryLimit", "$clusterTime": {"clusterTime": {"$timestamp": {"t": 1617712522, "i": 1}},  "keyId": 6903928055920590851}}}`

Comment: I am not highly skilled at writing the memory efficient queries. I will update you if I found some solution. Sorry!

Comment: Any idea about the solution for large collections?

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned I don't get the logic for field `batchId`. Apart from that, the simple solution could be this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $group: { _id: "$localityID", batches: { $push: { field1: "$field1", field2: "$field2" } } } },
   {
      $project: {
         localityID: "$_id",
         batches: { $slice: ["$batches", 1, 3] }
      }
   }
])
```